# Do Noroviruses include many families?

Tags: virus

Wikipedia says Caliciviridae Family.
My notes say that Norovirus includes the following

Noroviruses

- Norwalk-like viruses
- Caliciviruses
- Astroviruses and some small gastroenteroviruses

which is a larger definition including at least two families than the Wikipedia definition.
I think

- Caliciviruses $\subset$ Caliciviridae
- Astroviruses and some small gastroenteroviruses $\subset$ astroviridae

so the note is taking subsets among different families and classifying them into abstract class called **Noroviruses**.

**Extension based by Chris' excellent [answer](https://biology.stackexchange.com/a/17744/86).**

Criteria of Noroviruses

- (+)sense ssRNA viruses
- Structure and replication:

  - 1) only (+)sense ssRNA,
  - 2) simple nucleocapsid viruses,
  - 3) only viruses transmitted by fecal-oral route,
  - 4) size about 30 nm in diameter.

and then final classification of Noroviruses by these criteria

Noroviruses

- **Noroviruses** $\subset$ Norwalk-like viruses ($\subset$ F. Caliciviruses)
- Some Astroviruses ($\subset$ F. astroviridae) and some small gastroenteroviruses (what?)

which, however, does not make sense since Caliciviridae $\not\subset$ Astroviridae.
I do not understand what is the point of referring to the viruses by the sentence

> Astroviruses and some other round/small gastroenteris viruses

which are not part of Astroviridae.

**Which viruses of Caliciviridae are similar to *Astroviruses that are apparently round and small gastroenteritis viruses*?**

Comment: I don't understand your new question. What do you mean with understand? What is the purpose of your work?

Comment: @Chris Thank you for your comment! I included the criteria of classification for **Noroviruses**.

Comment: You want to know how the Norovirus was selected taxonomically?

Comment: @Chris Yes, I think so. In above definition, noroviruses include some viruses from Caliciviruses, Astroviruses and some other small gastroenteroviruses.

Comment: Which doesn't make sense. Ciliciviruses include Noroviruses, but not Astroviruses. The only belong to the same group.

Comment: @Chris Thank you for your comment! I added the criticism to the body. I think the last point is trying to refer to some viruses in Caliciviridae that have some characteristics of Astroviruses that are small/round gastroenteris viruses.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are mixing different things here: Virus are grouped based on their genetic material (dsDNA, ssDNA ssRNA and so on) into several groups (see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virus_classification) for details), then grouped into families, subgrouped into a genus and then into species.

So it is: Group > Family > Genus > Species.

What you have here are are different positions in this classification.
The names you mention belong all to the same tree:

Group: IV ([(+)ssRNA-Viruses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-sense_ssRNA_virus#Group_IV.E2.80.94positive-sense_ssRNA_viruses)) > Family ([Caliciviridae](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caliciviridae)) > Genus ([Norovirus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norovirus)) > Species ([Norwalk Virus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norwalk_virus)).

The [Astrovirus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astrovirus) belongs into the same group, but then form an own family.
To answer your question: No, since the Norovirus forms its own genus in the caliciviridae family.

Comment: Last sentence - do you mean genus (not family)?

Comment: Thank you, Chris, for your excellent answer! I have been completely confused by different naming systems that have been used. Besides those two systems, there seems to be also some conventions. I am trying to understand what is the initial point of making a abstract entity "Noroviruses" and including some viruses from different families into it.

Answer (score 1):

I take [NCBI's taxonomy](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/Taxonomy/Browser/wwwtax.cgi) any day over what wikipedia says. According to NCBI Caliciviridae includes Lagovirus, Nebovirus, Norovirus, Recovirus, Sapovirus, Vesivirus, Secalivirus, etc. For example:

Viruses; ssRNA viruses; ssRNA positive-strand viruses, no DNA stage; Caliciviridae; Norovirus; Norwalk virus; Chiba virus

Anyway, due to the absence of universal phylogenetic marker genes, viral taxonomy is mostly based on capsid shape and isn't thus very accurate..